an error when try to find an user using firebase in my ionic projet
the problem is that,I try to found a user in my firebase . when i put an error email it return 'user has found'
this my auth.service .ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import { Observable } from 'redux';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from 'src/app/model/user/user';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) { }


  recoverEmailPassword(email: string): Observable<void>{
    return new Observable<void>(observer =>{
      this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).then(()=>{
        observer.next();
        observer.complete();
      }).catch(error =>{
        observer.error(error);
        observer.complete();
         })
      
    })
  }


when i put an error email in my login page, it return true that the user has found. please help me
